# pdftk field names for insertion

Tags: pdf, field, pdftk, fdf

when I do  `pdftk samplex.pdf dump_data_fields`

I get back fields with format like:

```
  FieldType: Text
  FieldName: form1[0].Page1[0].Header[0].RepeatHeader[0].Project[0]
  FieldNameAlt: Project
  FieldFlags: 0
  FieldJustification: Left
```

I have a sample that works with pdftk in filling in the fields, but it is a simpler format and the FieldNames are things like 'name'.

I try to merge the following fdf to get my infill for this field (as you can see below I try both the long name and the short name), but it doesn't seem to be working, any ideas on why?:

```
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<< 
/FDF << /Fields [ << /V (Something wonderful!)/T <br/>(form1[0].Page1[0].Header[0].RepeatHeader[0].Project[0]) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V (Something)/T (Activity) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V (Something else)/T (Project) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V (Arthur, King of the Britons)/T (name) /ClrF 2 /SetFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (submit_name) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (name_border) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (name_border_red) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V (I seek the Holy Grail.)/T (quest) /ClrF 2 /SetFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (submit_quest) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (quest_border) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (quest_border_red) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V (Blue... no, yellow!)/T (color) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (submit_color) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (color_border) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (color_border_red) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (message_red) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
<< /V ()/T (message_green) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
] 
>> 
>> 
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R 

>>
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you generating your FDF? Here is an example FDF modified from a form I use pdftk with

field hierarchy like:

form1[0].Page1[0].Title[0]
form1[0].Page1[0].Item[0]
form1[0].Page1[0].Year[0]
form1[0].Page1[0].Desc[0]

```
%FDF-1.2 %���� 1 0 obj << 
    /FDF << 
        /Fields [
            << /T (form1[0]) /Kids [ 
                << /T (Page1[0]) /Kids [ 
                    << /T (Title[0]) /V (Android Phone) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
                    << /T (Item[0]) /V (Evo 3D) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >>
                    << /T (Year[0]) /V (2011) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
                    << /T (Desc[0]) /V (3D Smart Phone) /ClrF 2 /ClrFf 1 >> 
                ] >> 
            ] >> 
        ] 
    >> 
>> endobj trailer << /Root 1 0 R >> %%EOF
```

so you dont have the /Kids wrappers, and you arent using the field index numbers. Try modifying your FDF like my example to see if that works.

If you are a PHP user, you should check out pdftk-php. I use it on our server to inject mysql data into livecycle pdfs for a variety of uses and it takes care of the pdftk fdf injection part very nicely: http://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2009/06/19/pdftk-php-officially-released/